# How can I reconfigure the RAID settings on a Maxtor OneTouch III?

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, raid

I have a 1TB Maxtor OneTouch III. This is the drive that comes with two 500GB disks and software to configure RAID 0 (mirroring) with 500GB of storage, or full use of both disks for 1TB of storage. Way back when I set it up with RAID 0, and now I want to switch it back to no RAID.

Alas, Maxtor/Seagate do not make the software to do this available for download anymore. Naturally I don't have the DVD it came with (if there even was one!). Can anyone tell me where I can find a Mountain Lion or Lion utility to change the RAID configuration on this drive?

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I was able to come with was to borrow a Windows laptop and install the software there. Was enough for me to learn that one of the two disks in the drive was dead. :-(